# Getting a <div> and <a> to be the same height side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to add a custom style to the select2 jquery plug, it is a tag like multi selector plugin. The way that select2 renders selected "tags" guides my css rules to try and style. select2 renders a `<div>` containing the selected tag text followed by an `<a>` to remove that selected tag if the user desires.

I want the close btn and the tag text to look like one block. I have it almost where I want but you can see that the `<a>` element and the `div` element vary in height by a pixel or two. I thought maybe this was a display:inline versus display:block issue but I have tried setting both the elements to display:inline-block with no luck, here is a jsfiddle, just select both option1 and option2 to see my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/QRNqm/

And here is my code, remember I am using the select2 plugin also:

```
$(function(){
      $('#mdlTags').select2();
});


.select2-search-choice-close {
    padding: 2px 14px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: url(/images/projects/closeWhite.png) no-repeat 5px center #bdc6e5;
}
.select2-choices li div {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 14px 3px 12px;
    background-color: #bdc6e5;
}

 <select multiple="multiple" id="mdlTags" class="skipMsDropdown" style="width:330px;">
     <option value="1" >Option 1</option>
     <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Having you tried adding negative margin-top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.select2-search-choice-close` class with below:

```
.select2-search-choice-close {
    padding: 2px 14px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: url(/images/projects/closeWhite.png) no-repeat 5px center #bdc6e5;
    height: 14px; /* given height (actual 13px and 1px to adjust bottom margins) to adjust line-height of parent element */
    margin-top: -1px; /* to adjust top margins to get in proper line */
}
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QRNqm/1/).

Answer (score 1):

It's now on the same level. Here is the edited css.

```
.select2-search-choice-close {
    background: url("/images/projects/closeWhite.png") no-repeat scroll 5px center #BDC6E5;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px 14px 3px 0;  // increase the top padding for 1 point.
}

.select2-search-choice-close {
    background: url("select2.png") no-repeat scroll right top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 13px;
    outline: medium none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px; // Reduce the top position for 1 point
    top: 3px;
    width: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have one less pixel of top padding on the `select2-search-choice-close` style. But even once you fix that, there will still be a pixel of difference between the two elements.

If you take a look at the [demo on the Select2 page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi), that's the way it appears there as well (with one vertical pixel difference between the two elements). The difference is that they are applying the unifying style on the container that holds these two elements, rather than styling each of these elements separately.

If you make these two changes, you end up with something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cv6cH/